# hudson cobertura sonar integration error

Tags: maven, hudson, cobertura, sonarqube

I integrate sonar into hudson, but when I build a project using hudson, an error occured

log:[image: logInfo]

does anyone know how to avoid this error?
thanks in advance~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the location of you locale maven repository into a different location like c:.m2\ instead c:\Document Settgins etc........This can be done by changing the [settings.xml](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html) file.

You have reached the limit in Windows...